# Python iterating through nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-loops

First of all, here is the question and the code written:

```
def family_lineage(familytree, lineage):
    '''(dict, list of strs) -> boolean
    Return True if lineage specifies a list of names who are directly related
    in a chain of parent-child relationships, and NOT child-parent, parent-grandchild..etc,
    beginning from the first generation listed.

    >>> trace_lineage({'Gina': {'Sam': {'Tina': {}},
                           'Li': {}},
                   'Guy': {}},
                      ['Gina'])
    True

    >>> trace_lineage({'Gina': {'Sam': {'Tina': {}},
                               'Li': {}},
                       'Guy': {}},
                      ['Gina', 'Sam', 'Tina'])
    True
    >>> trace_lineage({'Gina': {'Sam': {'Tina': {}},
                               'Li': {}},
                       'Guy': {}},
                      ['Gina', 'Tina'])
    False
    '''
```

So, in the above example, it shows the 'Guy' has no children, and 'Gina' has two children, 'Sam', and 'Li'. 'Sam' has one child, 'Tina'.

```
for k, v in familytree.items():
    for n, m in v.items():
        if lineage[0] == any(k) and len(lineage) == 1:
            return True
        elif lineage[0] == k and lineage[1] == n and len(lineage) ==2:
            return True
        elif lineage[0] == k and lineage[1] == n and lineage[2] == m and \
        len(lineage) == 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

So, my question is, how would I write this if the familytree extended beyond three generations? Is there a more concise way of writing this code?

Comment: Make a recursive call, so it would work with a tree of any depth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in python, how do i iterate a nested dict with a dynamic number of nests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764892/in-python-how-do-i-iterate-a-nested-dict-with-a-dynamic-number-of-nests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an iterative approach that will work even if `lineage` does not start at the top of the family tree:

```
def family_lineage(familytree, lineage):
    trees = [familytree]
    while trees:
        tree = trees.pop()
        trees.extend(t for t in tree.values() if t)
        for name in lineage:
            if name not in tree:
                break
            tree = tree[name]
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Nice approach with using a queue.

Comment: Could you explain a bit on what you did? What was the purpose of putting familytree in square brackets, and then to use pop later on?
And when the code breaks, does it go directly to return False?

Comment: `trees` is a container of all unvisited branches in the tree, so `trees = [familytree]` is just giving us a starting point of the entire tree.  On each iteration of the while loop `trees.pop()` will give us a branch (node) of the tree to work with, and all non-empty children of that node are added to `trees`.  When the code breaks it does not go directly to return False, it just breaks out of the for loop.  The else clause on the for is only executed if there was no `break`, so this only returns True when every name in `lineage` is found.  We return False when all branches have been visited.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to see if you can traverse the tree; use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to loop over the elements and if a `KeyError` is raised, the path doesn't exist:

```
def family_lineage(familytree, lineage):
    if not familytree:
        return False
    try:
        reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], lineage, familytree)
        return True
    except KeyError:
        # No match at this level, recurse down the family tree
        return any(family_lineage(val, lineage) for val in familytree.itervalues())
```

`reduce()` applies the `lambda` function recursively to `lineage`, starting with `familytree`.

To support finding lineages deeper down the tree, you need to recurse down the tree on `KeyError`s.

Demo:

```
>>> tree = {'Gina': {'Sam': {'Tina': {}}, 'Li': {}}, 'Guy': {}}
>>> family_lineage(tree, ['Gina'])
True
>>> family_lineage(tree, ['Gina', 'Sam', 'Tina'])
True
>>> family_lineage(tree, ['Gina', 'Tina'])
False
>>> family_lineage(tree, ['Sam', 'Tina'])
True
```